# How do I modify an existing file to add the ability to unlink a specific file from a folder?

Tags: php

Thank you StackOverflow experts for looking at my question.

First, It is possible this question has been asked before but my situation is a bit unique. So, please hear me out.

When our users want to edit an existing record, they would also like to have the ability to delete an existing pdf file if one exists before adding a new one.

To display an existing file, I use this code.

```
         <td class="td_input_form">
         <?php
         // if the BidIDFile is empty,
         if(empty($result["BidIDFile"]))
         {
             //then show file upload field for Bid File
             echo '<input type="file" name="BidIDFile[]" size="50">';
         }
         else
         {
             // Bid file already upload, show checkbox to delete it.
             echo '<input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="'.$result["BidIDFile"].'"> (delete)
             <a href="http://uploads/'.$result["BidIDFile"].'" target="_blank" onclick="window.open (this.href, \'child\', \'height=800,width=850,scrollbars\'); return false" type="application/octet-stream">'.$result["BidIDFile"].'</a>';
         }
             </td>
```

Then to delete this file, I use the following code:

```
// Connect to SQL Server database
include("connections/Connect.php");

// Connect to SQL Server database
include("connections/Connect.php");

$strsID = isset($_GET["Id"]) ? $_GET["Id"] : null;

if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    // whilelisted table columns
    $fileColumnsInTable = array( 'BidIDFile', 'TabSheet', 'SignInSheet', 'XConnect',
                                 'Addend1', 'Addend2','Addend3','Addend4','Addend5', 'Addend6');

    $fileColumns = array();
    foreach ($_POST['delete'] as $fileColumn)
    {
        if(in_array($fileColumn, $fileColumnsInTable))
            $fileColumns[] = $fileColumn;
    }

    // get the file paths for each file to be deleted
    $stmts = "SELECT " . implode(', ', $fileColumns) . " FROM bids WHERE ID = ? ";
    $querys = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $stmts, array($strsID));
    $files = sqlsrv_fetch_array($querys,SQLSRV_FETCH_ROW);

    // loop over the files returned by the query
    foreach ($files as $file )
    {
        //delete file
        unlink($file);
    }

    // now remove the values from the table
    $stmts = "UPDATE bids SET " . impload(' = '', ', $fields) . " WHERE ID = ? ";
    $querys = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $stmts, array($strsID));
```

This works fine. However, the edit file points to an existing file with an INSERT and UPDATE operation in this one file (great thanks to rasclatt) and I am having problem integrating the two together.

Can someone please help with integrating the two files into one?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Here is the INSERT and UPDATE file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class   ProcessBid
    {
        public      $data;
        public      $statement;
        public      $where_vals;

        protected   $keyname;
        protected   $conn;

        public  function __construct($conn = false)
            {
                $this->conn =   $conn;
            }

        public  function SaveData($request = array(),$skip = false,$keyname = 'post')
            {
                $this->keyname              =   $keyname;
                $this->data[$this->keyname] =   $this->FilterRequest($request,$skip);

                return $this;
            }

        public  function FilterRequest($request = array(), $skip = false)
            {
                // See how many post variables are being sent
                if(count($request) > 0) {
                        // Loop through post
                        foreach($request as $key => $value) {
                                // Use the skip
                                if($skip == false || (is_array($skip) && !in_array($key,$skip))) {
                                        // Create insert values
                                        $vals['vals'][]   =   "'".ms_escape_string($value)."'";

                                        // Create insert columns
                                        $vals['cols'][]   =   "".str_replace("txt","",$key)."";

                                        // For good measure, create an update string
                                        $vals['update'][] =   "".str_replace("txt","",$key)."".' = '."'".ms_escape_string($value)."'";

                                        // For modern day binding, you can use this array
                                        $vals['bind']['cols'][]           =   "".$key."";
                                        $vals['bind']['cols_bind'][]      =   ":".$key;
                                        $vals['bind']['vals'][":".$key]   =   $value;
                                        $vals['bind']['update'][]         =   "".$key.' = :'.$key;
                                    }
                            }
                    }

                return (isset($vals))? $vals:false;
            }

        public  function AddFiles($name = 'item')
            {
                // If the files array has been set
                if(isset($_FILES[$name]['name']) && !empty($_FILES[$name]['name'])) {

                        // Remove empties
                        $_FILES[$name]['name']      =   array_filter($_FILES[$name]['name']);
                        $_FILES[$name]['type']      =   array_filter($_FILES[$name]['type']);
                        $_FILES[$name]['size']      =   array_filter($_FILES[$name]['size']);
                        $_FILES[$name]['tmp_name']  =   array_filter($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name']);

                        // we need to differentiate our type array names
                        $use_name   =   ($name == 'item')? 'Addend':$name;
                        // To start at Addendum1, create an $a value of 1

                        $a = 1;
                        if(!empty($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'])) {

                                 foreach($_FILES[$name]['name'] as $i => $value ) {
                                        $file_name  =   ms_escape_string($_FILES[$name]['name'][$i]);
                                        $file_size  =   $_FILES[$name]['size'][$i];
                                        $file_tmp   =   $_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'][$i];
                                        $file_type  =   $_FILES[$name]['type'][$i];

                                        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'][$i], $this->target.$file_name)) {
                                                // Format the key values for addendum
                                                if($name == 'item')
                                                    $arr[$use_name.$a]      =   $file_name;
                                                // Format the key values for others
                                                else
                                                    $arr[$use_name] =   $file_name;

                                                $sql    =   $this->FilterRequest($arr);

                                                // Auto increment the $a value
                                                $a++;
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }

                if(isset($sql) && (isset($i) && $i == (count($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'])-1)))
                    $this->data[$name]  =   $sql;

                return $this;
            }

        public  function SaveFolder($target = '../uploads/')
            {
                $this->target   =   $target;


                // Makes the folder if not already made.
                if(!is_dir($this->target))
                    mkdir($this->target,0755,true);

                return $this;
            }

        public  function where($array = array())
            {
                $this->where_vals   =   NULL;

                if(is_array($array) && !empty($array)) {
                        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
                                $this->where_vals[] =   $key." = '".ms_escape_string($value)."'";
                            }
                    }

                return $this;
            }

        public  function UpdateQuery()
            {
                $this->data         =   array_filter($this->data);

                if(empty($this->data)) {
                        $this->statement    =   false;
                        return $this;
                    }

                if(isset($this->data) && !empty($this->data)) {

                        foreach($this->data as $name => $arr) {
                                $update[] =   implode(",",$arr['update']);
                            }
                    }

                $vars       =   (isset($update) && is_array($update))? implode(",",$update):"";

                // Check that both columns and values are set
                $this->statement    =   (isset($update) && !empty($update))? "update bids set ".implode(",",$update):false;

                if(isset($this->where_vals) && !empty($this->where_vals)) {
                        $this->statement    .=  " where ".implode(" and ",$this->where_vals);
                    }

                return $this;
            }

        public  function SelectQuery($select = "*",$table = 'bids')
            {
                $stmt               =   (is_array($select) && !empty($select))? implode(",",$select):$select;

                $this->statement    =   "select ".$stmt." from ".$table;

                return $this;
            }

        public  function InsertQuery($table = 'bids')
            {
                $this->data         =   array_filter($this->data);

                if(empty($this->data)) {
                        $this->statement    =   false;
                        return $this;
                    }

                $this->statement    =   "insert into ".$table;

                if(isset($this->data) && !empty($this->data)) {

                        foreach($this->data as $name => $arr) {
                                $insert['cols'][] =   implode(",",$arr['cols']);
                                $insert['vals'][] =   implode(",",$arr['vals']);
                            }
                    }

                $this->statement    .=  '(';
                $this->statement    .=  (isset($insert['cols']) && is_array($insert['cols']))? implode(",",$insert['cols']):"";
                $this->statement    .=  ") VALUES (";
                $this->statement    .=  (isset($insert['vals']) && is_array($insert['vals']))? implode(",",$insert['vals']):"";
                $this->statement    .=  ")";

                return $this;
            }
    }

include("../Connections/Connect.php");
function render_error($settings = array("title"=>"Failed","body"=>"Sorry, your submission failed. Please go back and fill out all required information."))
    { ?>
<h2><?php echo (isset($settings['title']))? $settings['title']:"Error"; ?></h2>
<p><?php echo (isset($settings['body']))? $settings['body']:"An unknown error occurred."; ?></p>
<?php
    }

// this function is used to sanitize code against sql injection attack.
function ms_escape_string($data)
    {
        if(!isset($data) || empty($data))
            return "";

        if(is_numeric($data))
            return $data;

        $non_displayables[] =   '/%0[0-8bcef]/';    // url encoded 00-08, 11, 12, 14, 15
        $non_displayables[] =   '/%1[0-9a-f]/';     // url encoded 16-31
        $non_displayables[] =   '/[\x00-\x08]/';    // 00-08
        $non_displayables[] =   '/\x0b/';           // 11
        $non_displayables[] =   '/\x0c/';           // 12
        $non_displayables[] =   '/[\x0e-\x1f]/';    // 14-31

        foreach($non_displayables as $regex)
            $data   =   preg_replace($regex,'',$data);
            $data   =   str_replace("'","''",$data);
        return $data;
    }

    // New bid save engine is required for both sql statement generations
    $BidSet =   new ProcessBid($conn);
    $strId = null;

    if(isset($_POST["Id"]))
    {
        $strId = $_POST["Id"];
        //echo $strId;
    }
    If ($strId == "") {
    //echo "This is an insert statement";
    // This will generate an insert query
    $insert =   $BidSet->SaveData($_POST)
                        ->SaveFolder('../uploads/')
                        ->AddFiles('BidIDFile')
                        ->AddFiles('item')
                        ->AddFiles('SignInSheet')
                        ->AddFiles('TabSheet')
                        ->AddFiles('Xcontract')
                        ->InsertQuery()
                        ->statement;

    // Check that statement is not empty
    if($insert != false) {
            sqlsrv_query($conn,$insert);
            render_error(array("title"=>"Bid Successfully Saved!","body"=>'Go back to <a href="currentrecs.php">Solicitation screen</a>'));
            $err    =   false;
        }


    //echo '<pre>';
    //print_r($insert);
//  echo '</pre>';
    }
    else
    {
    //echo "This is an update statement";
    // This will generate an update query
    $update =   $BidSet->SaveData($_POST,array("Id"))
                        ->SaveFolder('../uploads/')
                        ->AddFiles('BidIDFile')
                        ->AddFiles('item')
                        ->AddFiles('SignInSheet')
                        ->AddFiles('TabSheet')
                        ->AddFiles('Xcontract')
                        ->where(array("Id"=>$_POST["Id"]))
                        ->UpdateQuery()
                        ->statement;

    //echo '<pre>';
    //print_r($update);
    //echo '</pre>';
    // Check that statement is not empty
    if($update != false) {
            sqlsrv_query($conn,$update);
            render_error(array("title"=>"Bid Successfully Saved!","body"=>'Go back to <a href="currentrecs.php">admin screen</a>'));
            $err    =   false;
        }
    }
    // This will post an error if the query fails
    if((isset($err) && $err == true) || !isset($err))
        render_error(); ?>
```

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until [no code can be removed while still running into the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: It should be pretty easy to integrate everything. If you email me, I can probably run you through it.